# On linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I'm currently studying for my linear algebra midterm and I'm having a tough time with the following question:

> If the following sets of vectors, {**u**, **v**}, {**u**, **w**}, {**v**, **w**}, are linearly independent, then is the set {**u**, **v**, **w**} linearly independent as well? ****EDIT**** Sorry, I forgot to mention **u**, **v**, **w** are in R3

When I first read this question, my intuition lead me to believe that  {**u**, **v**, **w**} must be linearly independent.
I reasoned that if {**u**, **v**}, {**u**, **w**}, {**v**, **w**} are all linearly independent, then there exists no linear combinations such that:

a * **u** = **w**
b * **v** = **w**

Therefore the following does NOT exist:

a * **u** + b * **v** = c * **w** =>

a * **u** + b * **v** c * **w** = 0

Where a, b, and c are all real numbers and a $\ne$ 0, b $\ne$ 0, c $\ne$ 0.

Therefore, the only solution for a * **u** + b * **v** c * **w** = 0 is a = b = c = 0.

Thus, {**u**, **v**, **w**} must be linearly independent. Are my assumptions correct?
If so, is there a better explanation? If not, where am I wrong?

***SOLUTION***
 Consider the vectors **u** = <1, 0, 0>, **v** = <0,1,0>, **c** = <1, 1,0>.
So, {**u**, **v**, **w**} is not necessarily linearly independent.

Comment: In a two-dimensional vector space, no set of three vectors can be linearly independent. Consider for example the vectors $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ in $\mathbb R^2$..

Comment: Surely, two bases in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ are linearly independent, but no set of three vectors is linearly independent..

Comment: Thank you both very much! The question also asked for an example of vectors if the system is linearly dependent, so I used u = <1, 0, 0>, v = <0,1,0>, c = <1, 1,0>.

Answer (score 0):

If $u.v$ are two linearly independent vectors then, defining $w$ as $u+v$, in the set $\{u,v,w\}$ any two will be linearly independent. But 
$1.u + 1.v -1.w=0$ so the set as a whole is linearly *dependent*. This is true in any vector space where you can find two linearly independent vectors.